# Java Generics. В чем разница Gen и Gen<?>

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть Generic:

```
public class Gen<T> {
    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

и какой-то метод:

```
public void someMethod(Gen<?> gen) {
    System.out.println(gen.getValue());
}
```

Будет ли какая-то разница, если параметр метода `someMethod` будет иметь тип `Gen` вместо `Gen<?>`?

Я понимаю, что метасимвольный аргумент может делать `extends` или `super`.

Я правильно понял, что Gen это способ решения проблем унаследованного кода?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данном случае разницы нет.

Разница существовала бы, если бы в классе Gen был метод, принимающий `T`:

```
public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

На `Gen` `setValue` выполнить можно, а на `Gen<?>` — нельзя.

Подстановочный параметр (wildcard) используется для установки ограничений на использование generic-класса. Методы, которые можно выполнить с классом `Gen<?>`, можно выполнить для любого `Gen<T>` без ошибок приведения типов.

Подробнее:

- [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#d5e3157)
- [Tutorial: Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)
- [Stackoverflow: Difference between an unbound wildcard and a raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242174/difference-between-an-unbound-wildcard-and-a-raw-type)